# RegEx : hardcoded capturing group value

Tags: regex, fluentd

I'm trying to write my own RegEx for my fluentd server.
Here is my regular expression :

```
^(?<server>)\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] (.*) \[(?<filename>[^\]]*)\:(?<line>[^\]]*)\](.*) To: (?<to>((?!\ \-\- Headers).)*)(.*) ((?=From:[ ]*(?<from>[^:]*) ([a-zA-Z\-:]*)))
```

With log exemple : https://regex101.com/r/yJ7rU4/1

I would like to define a value into my RegEx for my server group but I don't know how I can write it and if it's possible. This value is not writed on my parsed file, I want to put this information directly on my expression, something like this :

```
^(?<server>=serv1)\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] (.*) \[(?<filename>[^\]]*)\:(?<line>[^\]]*)\](.*) To: (?<to>((?!\ \-\- Headers).)*)(.*) ((?=From:[ ]*(?<from>[^:]*) ([a-zA-Z\-:]*)))
```

Comment: Where is the string for your server group? I don't see it in your sample

Comment: You want your regex to return a named capture group with a given, constant text that does not actually appear in the input string? This is not going to work with regex's only, because these can only return pieces of the input but not something that's not in the input.

Comment: @Fede Yea you are right, this server name are not in my input, I wanted to add it in my RegEx.

Comment: @HannoBinder awww ok :s it's so bad. Thanks

Comment: @Maxence posted an answer to do that, however your question would be accurately answered if a better sample would have been posted

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture some optional string if it exists and put it in your server group, then you have just to use a greedy quantifier with 0 or more... like this:

```
^(?<server>.*?)\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] (.*) \[(?<filename>[^\]]*)\:(?<line>[^\]]*)\](.*) To: (?<to>((?!\ \-\- Headers).)*)(.*) ((?=From:[ ]*(?<from>[^:]*) ([a-zA-Z\-:]*)))
           ^^^---Here
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJ7rU4/2)**

In case you want the server name is required you can use `+` operation

```
^(?<server>.+?)\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] (.*) \[(?<filename>[^\]]*)\:(?<line>[^\]]*)\](.*) To: (?<to>((?!\ \-\- Headers).)*)(.*) ((?=From:[ ]*(?<from>[^:]*) ([a-zA-Z\-:]*)))
           ^^^---Here
```

Comment: Thanks for your naswer but I can't write my server name in this parsed file, these log come from php mail log feature.

Comment: @Maxence I think you meant about my comment. How about the answer? did it solver you question?

Comment: Your answer works only if you can edit your input/sample, but in my case I can't edit my input. Like you said "if it exists" but server name information doesn't exist. That's why I wanted to add it manualy in my regex. So in my fluentd config file I just need to edit my regex to change my server name on each server. I hope I'm clear, sorry for my bad english :s

Comment: @Maxence I don't understand, you don't have a server name and you can't use a regex either ?